# How to display sub grids below a grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, material-ui

I'm relatively new to developing and I just started with react. I have a scenario here and iam not able to implement it. So my query is
As in picture below, I need to implement page like there are list of categories and I need to display them in grids( like I have gird1 grid2 grid3...... In below image). And on click of any category I need to display its sub categories in grid right below the selected category(if I click on grid 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 their sub grid should display below those grids). How can I implement this.
Hope u understood my query.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW8Lo.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by sub grids? Even after looking at your picture I still don't follow... are you wanting something like an [expansion panel](https://material-ui.com/components/expansion-panels/) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are rules against posting a solution that I haven't really developed, but a search on google brought me to this page in w3schools with an example:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_expanding_grid

I'm not sure if it would work on React, but it might be something you could adapt in your solution.